# Cannot ping to default gateway from computer inside private network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, file-sharing, tcpip

I have one desktop PC, laptop and android mobile. I have created a WiFi hotspot on my desktop PC so that I can use my internet on mobile as well on a laptop and it's working great, but now I want to send my files over WiFi, so am using Filezilla well, I can send my file from desktop-mobile but am not able to connect desktop and laptop but the internet is working on a laptop as well.

So I started tinkering around and I found that I cannot even ping to my default gateway from my laptop or vice versa (default gateway is my desktop PC).The error i get is Request timeout
**Desktop-Mobile**

```
C:\>ping 192.168.137.41

Pinging 192.168.137.41 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.137.41: bytes=32 time=265ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.41: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.41: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.41: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.137.41:
   Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
   Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 265ms, Average = 89ms
```

**Desktop-Laptop**

```
C:\>ping 192.168.137.22

Pinging 192.168.137.22 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.137.22:
   Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

**Laptop-Desktop**

```
C:\>ping 192.168.137.1

Pinging 192.168.137.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.137.1:
   Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

**Laptop arp-a**
    C:>arp -a

```
Interface: 192.168.137.22 --- 0xd
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.137.1         00-26-82-e1-07-72     dynamic
192.168.137.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
239.192.152.143       01-00-5e-40-98-8f     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Comment: i have disable my laptop firewall sorry i posted in wrong forum can i move it to SuperUser.com?

Comment: I wonder how many people get a twitchy eye whenever a stack site is called a forum...

Comment: my bad it's a QA site